# What counts as an array with no initialization?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I'm not sure about this two options:

example 1:

```
const int SIZE = 4;

int numbers[SIZE] = {};  //is this array initialized?

cout << numbers[0];
```

example 2:

```
const int SIZE = 4;

int numbers[SIZE]; // is this array initialized?

cout << numbers[0];
```

The problem with the second one is that the output is 4196112.

That means that "int numbers[SIZE] = { }" is not initialized right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think "initialized" means, but 4196112 is evidence that the array is *not* initialized, at least not zero initialized. Since you never supply any values for `numbers`, the best you can hope for in all these cases is for your array to be zero initialized. So 4196112 can't arise in these examples if you are actually initializing your array..

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment, an initialized variable has some known value. An uninitialized variable has an indeterminate value. An initialized variable does not mean a variable with a non-zero value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int numbers[SIZE] = {}` performs agregate initialization, which for `int`s means value initialization, which means they all get initialized to 0.

`int numbers[SIZE];` declares an array of uninitialised `int`s.

Note: Iff the array has static storage duration, it IS initialized with zeros, even without an explicit = {}.

Also, agregate initialization lets you specify some initializers and the rest will then be initialized to zero (or whatever is the default for their type).

Comment: *UNLESS* the array is declared in global scope, in which case it IS initialized with zeros, even without an explicit `= {}` initializer.

Comment: I would clarify that aggregate initialization lets you specify values for elements in the aggregate, but then value-initializes all the remaining ones.

Comment: Global scope of namespace scope? Edit : I believe static and thread local storage also gets zero initialized.

Comment: `Iff the array is declared in global scope`: Almost. If the array is "Static Storage Duration" which includes global scope and static variables in function scope.

Comment: Updated the answer. Better now?